# SQL Server -> Linked Server to Oracle: "inconsistent metadata" on n+1st query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I use LinkedServer to connect SQL-Server with Oracle.

No matter if I use openquery or not, I can only query one single action like "delete" or "insert" on my LinkedServer-Connection. For the n+1st query, I get the following error from SQL-DB:

> The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "NAME"
> supplied inconsistent metadata. An extra column was supplied during
> execution that was not found at compile time.

When I check sessions on OracleDB, I can see that immediately after my query, there is an inactive session from the SQL-Server-Host with a wait-event "SQL*Net message from client". This inactive session disappears after about 60s. Until then, I cannot query any other actions on my LinkedServer-Connection - unless I kill this session manually.

How can I prevent this session from being created and blocking further queries?

Linked-Server-Config:

- Provider: Oracle Provider for OLE DB
- Provider-Options: "Level zero only" = TRUE, "Allow inprocess" = TRUE
- Linked-Server Options: default

Thanks in advance,

Martin

**EDIT: Minimal-Repro**

At first, I insert data into empty oracle table via

```
INSERT OPENQUERY 
(LINK, 'select COLUMNS from LINKED_TABLE') VALUES (VALUES);
```

This works.

Next, I insert more data into oracle table, e.g.

```
INSERT OPENQUERY 
    (LINK, 'select COLUMNS from LINKED_TABLE') VALUES (DIFFERENT_VALUES);
```

Now, I get the following error in SSMS:

> Msg 7353, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LINK" supplied inconsistent metadata. An extra column was supplied during execution that was not found at compile time.

If I check oracle sessions, I can see that there is an inactive connection-session for my SQL-Server-Host. Only if I kill this connection-session in Oracle SQL Developer, I can insert (or delete/update) more data. "Select" works without problems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you create and post a minimal repro? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DavidBrowne: added minimal repro. Same issue has been discussed under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/98208/linked-server-throws-metadata-error.html

Comment: It turns out to be an oracle-bug:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275605/linked-server-throws-metadata-error